# Size of rails generated radio buttons in a mobile app that uses jquery mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

In a rails 3.0 app that uses jquery mobile for mobile devices I have a series of radio buttons   with responses 0 through 2.

```
<%= f.radio_button :field_name, 2 %>
<%= f.radio_button :field_name, 1 %>
<%= f.radio_button :field_name, 0 %>
```

These radio buttons are way too small to see well, and use, on a mobile touch screen. I tried enclosing them in the tags for jquery mobile like so:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Enjoy</legend>
        <%= f.radio_button :field_name, 2 %>
        <%= f.label :field_name, "blah" %>
        <%= f.radio_button :field_name, 1 %>
        <%= f.label :field_name, "blah" %>
        <%= f.radio_button :field_name, 0 %>
        <%= f.label :field_name, "blah" %>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

They still come out small. I could use html instead of rails to produce the buttons, but I'd rather not. Is there an option to increase the size of the rails produced radio buttons? Is there a way to manipulate the rails code to produce the html that will result in jquery mobile format? Is there another possibility i haven't thought of?

Thanks.

BTW, there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087976/translating-ruby-radio-buttons-into-jquery-mobile-radio-buttons) question but it has no answer and it hasn't been updated since Nov '11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style your radio buttons with CSS:

```
.radio_buttons_class {
    height:6em;
    width:6em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can just use the "label for" html to get the jQuery Mobile grouped button "look" (no extra CSS required). Just view the source of the generated radio buttons and match the label to the button id:

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      <legend>Enjoy</legend>

          <%= f.radio_button :field_name, 0 %>
          <label for="field_name_0">Zero</label>

         <%= f.radio_button :field_name, 1 %>
         <label for="field_name_1">One</label>

          <%= f.radio_button :field_name, 2 %>
          <label for="field_name_2">Two</label>
       </fieldset>
</div>
```